# Count entries from different tables per day

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
reports:
    date, uuid
warns:
    date, uuid, active
```

Where `date` is a timestamp *(2016-05-16 16:06:58)*, `uuid` is a user-identifier string and `active` is a boolean.

I want to display how many `reports` and `warns` entries there are per day. Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT DATE(date) Date, count(*) Reports
FROM reports
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY DATE(date) DESC
```

Which displays a table like this:

```
Date       | Reports 
-----------+---------
2016-07-05 | 192     
2016-07-04 | 230     
2016-07-03 | 227
```

But I also want to join in how many `warns` entries occurred that day but only if it's `active` column is `TRUE`, so I want the query to return a table like this:

```
Date       | Reports | Warns
-----------+---------+-------
2016-07-05 | 192     | 47
2016-07-04 | 230     | 59
2016-07-03 | 227     | 56
```

I am a newbie at MYSQL so I haven't been able to figure out how I would do this yet. I searched a bit on JOINS and UNIONS but didn't know if/how they applied to my case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated query:

```
SELECT DATE(reports.date) Date, count(*) Reports,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warns
        WHERE DATE(warns.date) = DATE(reports.date) and warns.active = 'TRUE') as warns_cnt
FROM reports
GROUP BY DATE(reports.date)
ORDER BY DATE(reports.date) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate union you could:-

```
/*
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE REPORTS (DTE DATE, UUID INT);
TRUNCATE TABLE REPORTS;
INSERT INTO  REPORTS VALUES
('2016-07-05' , 192     ),
('2016-07-05' , 192     ),
('2016-07-05' , 192     ),
('2016-07-04' , 230     ),
('2016-07-04' , 230     ),
('2016-07-03' , 227     ),
('2016-07-02' , 227     );

DROP TABLE WARNS;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WARNS (DTE DATE, UUID INT,ACTIVE INT);
INSERT INTO  WARNS VALUES
('2016-07-05'      , 47,0),
('2016-07-05'      , 47,1),
('2016-07-05'      , 47,1),
('2016-07-04'      , 59,0),
('2016-07-03'      , 56,1),
('2016-07-03'      , 56,1),
('2016-07-03'      , 56,1);
*/


SELECT  S.DTE, SUM(S.REPORTS) REPORTS, SUM(S.WARNS) WARNS
FROM         
(
SELECT DTE,1 AS REPORTS, 0 AS WARNS  FROM REPORTS 
UNION ALL
SELECT DTE,0, 1 FROM WARNS WHERE ACTIVE = TRUE 
) S
GROUP BY S.DTE
```

The query create REPORTS and WARNS columns in the subquery which are then summed outside the subquery.